# How to import the text file with special character

Tags: r, tidyverse

I am new to RStudio.
I am trying to import the following text into Rstudio. The file type is .txt. I would like to remove the first 6 rows (all the text).

```
AAA: true
BBB: false
CCC: 0
DDD: Wavelengths
EEE: 3648
>>>>>Begin Decimal Data<<<<<
623.821 -216.03
623.881 -216.03
623.941 -216.03
```

Then I would like to create the data.table, separating into two columns: Col A and Col B as follow.

```
Col A  Col B
623.821 -216.03
623.881 -216.03
623.941 -216.03
```

Could you please help me how I could code this?

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. Please look up the R help documentation for `read.delim()`, particularly skip, header and col.names. It should be possible to do all that you require in one line. Make an attempt and document it, then ask for feedback if you still have questions after that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the function `read.table` and play with the `skip` argument. It specifiy the number of line you want to skip.
For having two columns, the default separator between column is a space character which seems to be the case in your file (if you need to change it, it is the `sep` argument).
I strongly encourage you to read the help where it is really understandable (you can use F1 in Rstudio when your cursor is on a function to access it fast).

The solution could be something like:

```
dat <- read.table('directory/myfile.txt', skip = 6)
```

EDIT

If you also want to give names to your column you can use `names` or `colnames` like this:

```
names(dat) <- c("Col_A", "Col_B")
```

It is a good practice to not use space in names as it can be a problem later

Comment: Thanks , Glastos! Actually, I have a series of .txt files. So, I would like to combine, and delete the rows and separate the columns. I coded as follow:

files <- dir(".", pattern = ".txt$") 
for (i in 1:length(files)) {
  obj_name <- files %>% str_sub(start = -2)
  assign(obj_name[i], read_table(files[i], skip = 13)) 
  names(obj_name[i]) <- c("Col_A", "Col_B")
}

But it shows the error in the separate comment:

Comment: -- Column specification -------------------------------------------------------------
cols(
  `>>>>>Begin` = col_double(),
  Spectral = col_double(),
  `Data<<<<<` = col_character()
)

Warning: 3648 parsing failures.
row col  expected    actual                 file
  1  -- 3 columns 2 columns 'L1_0401_0603_B.txt'
  2  -- 3 columns 2 columns 'L1_0401_0603_B.txt'
  
... ... ......... ......... ....................
See problems(...) for more details.
Error in names(obj_name[i]) <- c("Col_A", "Col_B") : 
  'names' attribute [2] must be the same length as the vector [1]

Comment: It is difficult for me to say where is the problem but it may come from the fact that one file has not the same number of line to skip or column and it cause a problem. Are you sure all the file show consistency for these two parameters ?

Comment: Yes, I checked the number of files are inconsistent. Now I am changing a different way, thanks!